# Change jQuery(document).ready to $.delegate in wordpress

Tags: jquery

I am trying to change:

```
add_action('wp_footer','myscript_in_footer');
function myscript_in_footer(){
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
  jQuery(document).ready(function(){
   jQuery("div.domTip_tipBody").mouseover(function(){
   jQuery("#yyy a.tippy_link").css("background-color","yellow");});  

   jQuery("div.domTip_tipBody").mouseout(function(){
   jQuery("#yyy a.tippy_link").css("background-color","red");
 }); 
 });  
 </script>
<?php
}
```

To

```
add_action('wp_footer','myscript_in_footer');
function myscript_in_footer(){
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
  function(){
    $.delegate('p','mouseover', function(e){ 
    jQuery("#yyy a.tippy_link").css("background-color","yellow");}); 

   $.delegate('p','mouseout', function(e){
    jQuery("#yyy a.tippy_link").css("background-color","red");
 }); 
 });  
 </script>
<?php
}
```

The first one works but the second one dose not.

The reason for the change is that I have elements that are output by a shortcode (e.g "div.domTip_tipBody") that the first function is not reading and it was suggested that the second method might work, but I can not get the second method functioning even with the element 'p'.

Thanks
Tim

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you're missing the jQuery ready function. Try this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $.delegate('p','mouseover', function(e){ 
        $("#yyy a.tippy_link").css("background-color","yellow");
    }); 

    $.delegate('p','mouseout', function(e){
        $("#yyy a.tippy_link").css("background-color","red");
    }); 
});
```

Cheers,

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply dunc.  I tried your code still not working. Any other ideas?

Comment: Try substituting the other two occurrences of "jQuery" in the code with "$". There should only be use of "jQuery" once in that snippet.

Comment: Whoops, yeah! I've edited my post. Try that.

Comment: Again thanks for the response dunc, did as you said, sill not working.

Comment: Here is what worked`jQuery(document).ready(function(){
   jQuery("*").delegate("div.domTip_tipBody","mouseover",function(){
    jQuery("#yyy a.tippy_link").css("background-color","#392281");
    }); 
    
   jQuery("*").delegate("div.domTip_tipBody","mouseout",function(){
    jQuery("#yyy a.tippy_link").css("background-color","transparent");
    }); 
   });`

Comment: it only worked with the "jQuery", "$" broke the function. Thanks dunc